# Loading in a large .rds file kills screen

Tags: r, ssh, bigdata

I have large datasets stored in .rds files (the object itself is a nested list, at the bottom of which are data frames) that I want to load into an environment to use.

I'm using an SSH connection to do this work, and about half the time, when I try to load in the .rds file, doing so kills the screen I'm using.

I suspect this is happening because the files are too large (~15GB), so maybe there's not a way around this, but I figured I'd ask, just in case!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!